# ZendFramework - How to get Page ID Name

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db-table

I have a table ***sitepage_manageadmins*** which contain: " user_id, page_id ".
There is another table ***sitepage_pages*** which contain " page_id, title ".

Im trying to render as dropdown ( select list ) in Zend_Form the user which is admin to relevant page_id .

Here is my code:

```
$this->view->owner_id = $viewer_id = $viewer->getIdentity();  // get $viewer
$adminpages = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('manageadmins', 'sitepage')->getManageAdminPages($viewer_id); // get viewer page_id's where is admin
```

Getting the page_id as dropdown list:

```
$ids = array ( 0 => '-- Select --');
    foreach ($adminpages as $adminpage) {
        $ids[] = $adminpage->page_id;
    }
```

Rendering the dropdown

```
$this->addElement('select', 'page_id', array (
                'label' => 'Page where I'm Admin',
                'multioptions' => $ids,
));
```

For now, im only render the Page_ID numbers as dropdown. I want from Specific Page_ID to render the Title.

Any ideas are welcome?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are putting only the ids to the `$ids[]` array The multioption array should be key-value pair in this case page_id as key & page_title as value.
`foreach ($adminpages as $adminpage) {

$ids[$adminpage->page_id] = $adminpage->page_title;

}`

Comment: Regarding to my connection from database, my table dosen't have field page_title, so if i connect on this way, im getting error.

The solution i think is to join where sitepage_pages have Page ID from manageadmins viewer ID, and from that ID To get the Page Title.

Comment: sorry for that.. i thought you had joined it already in `getManageAdminPages()`. Got confused with `page_id` from the two tables

Comment: `$select = $this->select()   

 ->from('sitepage_manageadmins')   

 ->joinLeft(array('page'=>'sitepage_pages''),'page.page_id ='sitepage_manageadmins.page_id', array('page.page_id AS pageid','title AS page_title'))   

 ->where('user_id = ?', $viewer_id);   
 `

Comment: Im getting PHP Error on :
'page.page_id ='sitepage_manageadmins.page_id'

Comment: can you specify the error. you can see the query by `die($select)`

Comment: This is the error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')'

Comment: this error occurs when there is a syntax issues due to missing quotes, brackets .. you should paste the code in some editor and check if the syntax is proper

Comment: $select = $this->select()  ->from('sitepage_manageadmins')  ->joinLeft(array('page'=>'sitepage_pages'),'page.page_id = sitepage_manageadmins.page_id', array('page.page_id AS pageid','title AS page_title'))  ->where('user_id = ?', $viewer_id);